# What is Xcode doing when it is indexing a new developer device?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, indexing, device

I was installing an app on the device of a friend for testing purposes. Before Xcode did so, I had to register the device and Xcode indicated that it was 'indexing' the device.

**What does 'indexing' do in this context ?**

I understand the general concept of indexing, and I know this process will enable the developer section in the settings (and other things) but that would rather be 'Preparing device for developing' and not 'indexing'.

Comment: I think that you talk about the "Processing symbol files". It happens when you plug a new device to your Mac for the first time while Xcode is opened. The "Processing symbol files" is to collect debug symbol file in order to 'symbolicate' the crash log. The message "indexing" that you have seen must be related to the indexing of your project source code, not for the device. I suppose Xcode did the both in same time so made you confused.

Answer (score -1):

I think indexing refers to adding it as a device to your account developer panel at: https://developer.apple.com/account

In certificates, Identifiers & Profiles you can see your devices.
[image]